# Is it good practice to use requirejs to extend single pages instead of pure javascript applications?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, requirejs

So my question is mainly about the use case of RequireJS.

I read a lot about pure javascript driven web pages. Currently I extend single rendered views (e.g. provided by a PHP Framework) with AngularJS which adds a lot of value.
Sadly the dependency management gets harder and harder with every `<script>` tag on other 'single pages'. Even more when there is a `main.js` file which provides common libraries (e.g. jQuery and AngularJS itself).

I thought this doesn't fit into RequireJS philosophy to have *one main file* which requires all dependencies.

A good example would be an administration panel which uses some modules (defined by AngularJS's dependencies).

**Example:**

```
scripts/
    adminpanel/
        panel.app.js
        panel.filters.js
        panel.directives.js
    antoherModule/
    andAntoherModule/
    require.js
```

#### tl;dr

When you use AngularJS to extend single pages, instead of building a completely javascript driven web application, is it good practice to use RequireJS for AMD loading modules which will be used on the single page ? And how is the best way to do it so ?

Comment: What is the difference between a "pure javascript driven" web page and an Angular.js driven webpage?

Comment: The difference i mean is about a single page (e.g. a php framework which just provides single rendered pages) and pure javascript driven webpages (e.g. the [AngularJS seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed))

Answer (score 0):

[SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) usually means that the page doesn't refresh and all extra content is loaded on the fly.  In essence the entire app is a single page.  It doesn't mean that all of the content is loaded on the initial load (though if it is small enough, this could be the case).  Using RequireJS / AMD architecture is really good for this kind of thing.

As the user navigates throughout the site, different partials / templates are retrieved as well as any supporting JavaScript.

The best way to do this is with [define](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#funcmodule).  Defining all of the requirements your script needs in order to work.  All of the scripts needed will be loaded before the function is run, ensuring that you have everything you need. Furthermore, the items that you define as requirements can have their own define to specify the scripts they need... and so on.